# File Extension getting changed for few content types when downloaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I  am using the below method to download the file from server  now for few files with extensions (".png",".txt",".pdf") the  files are downloading correctly but where as for (".exe") the file is downloading as f.txt may  i know what's wrong with this code.For .exe files  the content is being written to a "f.txt" file . I am also usoing *Files.probeContentType(file.toPath());* to determine the media type and setting it in content type of respnse entity.Thanks in advance! :).
the media type where extension changing is *application/x-msdownload*

```
        public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFileFromDisk(String filename) throws IOException {
            ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> filedata = null;
            String file_path = "/e:/filesfolder/" + filename;
            String fileType = "Undetermined";
            final File file = new File(file_path);
            fileType = Files.probeContentType(file.toPath());
            System.out.println(fileType);
            InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file_path));
            String file_checksum = checksumcalc.calculateChecksum(file_path);
            filedata = ResponseEntity.ok().header("Md5", file_checksum)
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(fileType)).body(resource);
            return filedata;
        }
```

Comment: what is the output of filetype if a filename contains .exe.

Comment: it stores in f.txt file  and the content of .exe file the contents are same but the file is getting renamed and extension is changed for .exe file

Comment: Are you store .txt on uploading .exe

Comment: no while storing it is storing as .exe only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the `f.txt` issue, you have to define the `Content-disposition` header to specify the filename of the attachment.

For example :

```
filedata = ResponseEntity.ok()
    .header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
    .header("Md5", file_checksum)
    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(fileType)).body(resource);
```

Comment: From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) : In a regular HTTP response, the Content-Disposition response header is a header indicating if the content is expected to be displayed inline in the browser, that is, as a Web page or as part of a Web page, or as an attachment, that is downloaded and saved locally.